# design schema for mysql for questionnaire with fixed questions

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, database-design

I am designing schema for questionnaire with fixed questions.

There are several independent questionnaire(e.g. Family/Friends/School etc).
The questionnaire does not need registration to do it, so NO User relationship we need to handle.

The questionnaire seems like below:
[image]

However the options are different between different questionnaire.
[image]

I am thinking using only one Table `Survey` to store all the data such as storing the answer of a questionnaire with an array, since the questionnaires are not gonna change.

```
{
   surveyId: 123 (which is the primary key),
   type: "School",   // values: Family/School etc
   answer: [0,1,0,1,2....]
}
```

Besides, there are some analytics needed to be made based on the questionnaire results

```
1. Count scores for a specific questionnaire
2. Count the percentage of answer selection for a certain question
```

Is there any suggestion for the schema?

Answer (score 1):

While I can't claim that this is the definitive solution, I would expect to see something along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE questionaire_types
(questionaire_type_id SERIAL PRIMARY
,questionaire_type_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO questionaire_types VALUES
(1,'fortnight frequency'),
(2,'agreement');


CREATE TABLE questionaire_type_detail
(questionaire_type_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,option_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
,option_value VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO questionaire_types VALUES
(1,1,'not at all'),
(1,2,'occasionally'),
(1,3,'often'),
(1,4,'nearly every day'),

(2,1,'strongly agree'),
(2,2,'agree'),
(2,3,'neutral'),
(2,4,'disagree'),
(2,5,'strongly disagree');

CREATE TABLE questionaires
(questionaire_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,questionaire_type_id
,question VARCHAR(50) NULL
);

INSERT INTO questionaires VALUES
(1,1,1,"Over the last 2 weeks, how often have been bothered by any of the following problems?"),
(2,2,NULL);

CREATE TABLE questionaire_subquestions
(subquestion_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,questionaire_id INT NOT NULL
,subquestion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO questionaire_subquestions VALUES
(1,1,'Little interest or pleasure in doing things'),
(2,1,'Feeling down, depressed, or hopeless'),
(3,1,'Trouble falling/staying asleep, sleeping too much'),
(4,1,'Feelng tired or having little energy'),
(5,1,'Poor appetite or overeating'),
(6,1,'Etc...'),
(...)
(10,2,'The store is accessibly located'),
(11,2,'Store hours are convenient for my dining needs'),
(12,2,'Advertised dish was in stock'),
(13,2,'A good selection of dishes was present'),
(14,2,'Etc...'),

CREATE TABLE responses
(response_id INT NOT NULL
,subquestion_id INT NOT NULL
,selected_option_id
,PRIMARY KEY(response_id,subquestion_id)
);
```